# Quickblox android chat - audio attachment uploading failed

Tags: java, android, chat, quickblox

I am trying to upload an audio file using quickblox api. I am able to upload audio attachment in my Nexus 7. The issue is, when I try to upload audio files using the same code, in other available devices (Asus zenphone and Karbonn Android one) , I am getting quickblox response exception. The exception is "content_type is too short (minimum is 5 characters),content_type is invalid". Please someone help me with this exception. I am getting exception in the following block.

```
   /** 
     * This method will invoke when user try to upload a file in the chatbox.
     *
     * @param dialogId
     * @param inputFile
     * @param messageId
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     *
     **/

public QBFile loadAttachFile(String dialogId, final File inputFile, final String messageId) throws Exception {
    QBFile file = null;

    try {
        file = QBContent.uploadFileTask(inputFile, true, (String) null,
                new QBProgressCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(int arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (!lastUpdatedProgress.contains(arg0)) {
                            lastUpdatedProgress.add(arg0);
                            //Here we will update the progress of the progressbar details
                            updateAttachmentUploadingProgress(messageId, arg0);
                        }

                    }
                });
    } catch (QBResponseException exc) {
        throw new Exception(context.getString(R.string.dlg_fail_upload_attach) );
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: Please post your logs and also how yo create 'inputFile'

Comment: The InputFile is ".aac" format. I am able to create and store the audio file in local storage of Asus zenphone and Karbonn Android one. Even I can listen to the created audio file from same device (Incase if you think that the created audio file is corrupted). The issue (quickblox response exception) happens, only when I try to upload the file.

Comment: Let us check ".acc" with Asus

Comment: Ok. please note that the audio format which I am trying to upload is in **".aac"** format, not **".acc"**. I am facing issue in specifically Asus zenphone and Karbonn Android one devices

Comment: Yes, checking 'aac' and  Asus zenphone

Comment: Have you got any solution?. Please help me, I am running out of time already :(

Comment: Yes, we found a root problem with acc audio container. New SDK version is going to release. Will update you shortly

Comment: Here it is http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with 'acc' file format and 'android.webkit.MimeTypeMap' class

QuickBlox has released the Android SDK 2.3 version with the fix
http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog

Check it out